# F# BinarySearch return position

Tags: f#, functional-programming, binary-search

I'm trying to implement a simple binary search in F# as a way of learning functional programming. I've already implemented it in an imperative way in C# which is my main language, but I thought it would be a nice challenge and a good way to learn functional concepts by implementing it in a recursive sense in F#. I've gotten far enough that it properly finds the value, my problem is that I want the function to return -1 if the value is not in the array, and the index of the value otherwise, but I can't come up with a good way of keeping track of the index. Here's my code:

```
let rec chop i (nums:array<int>) =
match nums with
| [||] -> -1
| [|x|] -> if x = i then x else -1
| _ -> 
    let mid = nums.Length / 2 in
    if nums.[mid] < i then (chop i nums.[mid..])
    elif nums.[mid] > i then (chop i nums.[..mid])
    else mid

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%d" (chop 20 (Array.init 100 (fun index -> index * 2)))
    System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Since I split the list every iteration, I will get different indices when I move "up" into the array. In my example, the code returns 3 instead of 10.

What's the recommended way of fixing this? Any way to solve it is appreciated, though I would obviously prefer "correct" ways of doing it in a functional sense, since that's what I'm practicing. I would also like any advice concerning if my solution is bad from a performance point of view (for example, is it a bad idea to split the arrays in the first place?)

Comment: BTW: you could still *repair* your go if you pass around an offset-index (where your current array starts in regard to the original one)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would stick more with the original without copying the array (and use `Option` instead of the magic number `-1` for failures):

```
let chop i (nums : int[]) =
    let rec find a b =
        if b < a then None else
        let mid = (a+b)/2
        let midValue = nums.[mid]
        if midValue = i then 
            Some mid 
        elif i < midValue then
            find a (mid-1)
        else
            find (mid+1) b
    find 0 (nums.Length-1)
```

maybe you don't like all these `if`s but still this is the obvious translation of the algorithm. And it does not mutate or reallocate anything.

If you want to remove the ifs you can do this:

```
let chop i (nums : int[]) =
    let rec find a b =
        if b < a then None else
        let mid = (a+b)/2
        match (compare i nums.[mid]) with
        | 0  -> Some mid
        | -1 -> find a (mid-1)
        | 1  -> find (mid+1) b
        | _  -> failwith "should never happen"
    find 0 (nums.Length-1)
```

even more readable (but a bit boilerplatey):

```
[<Literal>] 
let Lt = -1
[<Literal>] 
let Gt = +1


let chop i (nums : int[]) =
    let rec find a b =
        if b < a then None else
        let mid = (a+b)/2
        match (compare i nums.[mid]) with
        | Lt -> find a (mid-1)
        | Gt -> find (mid+1) b
        | Eq -> Some mid
    find 0 (nums.Length-1)
```

(*remark* please note that the last case is really a match all case I should probably write as `| _ -> Some mid` but I think in this case I may cheat for *readabilities* sake)

Performancewise the only thing you could improve is removing the recursion (but that should not be a problem if you enable optimization)

### remark

as @kvb rightly noted `(a+b)/2` is a bit of a risk (and I make this mistake regualary) - so if you have really big arrays and want to be safe better use this instead:

```
let mid = a + (b - a) / 2
```

which is of course mathematically the same but for finite ranges and with overflow quite a difference

Comment: Good answer, but note that for very large arrays `(a+b)/2` can end up overflowing during the addition and resulting in a negative index.  See http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html.

Comment: @kvb - yes right - you think I should change it here? (this value is far more readable than the **right** implementation IMO)

Comment: [A slightly cleaner way](https://gist.github.com/simtali/c2e7d645aea0cda84e8e), IMO, not requiring an "impossible" case.

Comment: why don't you add it as an answer @Daniel (I cannot steal others good ideas all day :D ) - but you are right I should get rid of it (now that I think about it it's really easy ;) )

Answer (score 5):

A slight variation, that doesn't require an "impossible" case:

```
let binarySearch value (array: 'T[]) =
    let rec loop lo hi =
        if lo <= hi then
            let mid = lo + ((hi - lo) >>> 1)
            match array.[mid] with
            | x when x = value -> Some mid
            | x when x < value -> loop (mid + 1) hi
            | _ -> loop lo (mid - 1)
        else None
    loop 0 (array.Length - 1)
```